# How do I responsively arrange images in a single line within a div

Tags: html, css, wrapper, fluid-layout

I'm trying to place links on images in one row so that different images have different links. I'm also having this div to shrink to fit certain media screen sizes. However, the images didn't resize according to the wrapper requirements. Please help.

Here's the HTML:

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    text-align: center;
    background: url(image/bg.png) center top;
  }
  #wrapper {
    width: 768px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    text-align: center;
    background: url(image/bg.png) center top;
  }
  #wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="image/pea.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="image/pea_01.jpg">
    <img src="image/pea_02.jpg">
    <img src="image/pea_03.jpg">
    <img src="image/pea_04.jpg">
    <img src="image/pea_05.jpg">
  </div>
  
  <!-- main issue here -->
  <div class="box">
    <img src="image/pea_footer.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot of the line up (desktop). Mobile seems to look ok after adding display:inline-block; 
width:auto; to .box:
[image: x]

Comment: you can add this css 

    .box {display:inline-block; width:auto;}

Comment: got it work on mobile view! but desktop view is still not aligned, please see attached image on edit, please help.

Comment: you can add float: left in css may be it will work

Answer (score 1):

I reckon remove any static widths because you only need to detect when the viewport is a certain size and then change the img width then, as I have done here. I set each image to display block to remove any margin or padding around them. You might prefer to not do this, but I like setting this as default.

This way you can pick different breakpoints that suit you rather than setting static widths at each breakpoint. This is the beauty of responsive development. Stay flexible rather than controlling what happens to containing divs; let the content run things. Run this snippet below in Full Screen mode to see the full desktop styling (each img goes to 20% instead of 50%):

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
img {
width: 50%;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></a>
  </div>
  
  <!-- main issue here -->
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried and tweak the codes a bit but the images came out all in 1 line verticle, I wanted them to be horizontal. Sorry, was not being specific...

Comment: Hi, I used your html code, they are all horizontal in each .box grouping.

Comment: ok got it to work! had to slice them perfectly at 20%. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your .box could be in `display:flex`

```
.box {
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: row nowrap;
     justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Keep in mind that your 5 `<img>` should be the icons, not containing your `background` (the clouds).
And I think the following code would be correct for your images:

```
.box img {
     max-width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to not apply an explicit width or height to the image tag.
Please try:

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```

Just use percentage based layouts rather than pixels or other measurements.
For example:

```
<img width="50%">: that will fill half of the containing element, at any size
<img width="500px">: that will always fill exactly 500 pixels, if it's too big or if it's too small.
```

Comment: Thank you for the revision. yeah... it's the "containing element" size not the "screen" size.